# RBS filestream is not being cleared when SPSite is moved to another DB in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, rbs

When we move the site collection from RBS enabled content DB to normal content DB in SharePoint 2010, RBS filestream is not being cleared.

Even though, IIS have been reset, executed the RBS maintainer and Run the checkpoint on the RBS enabled DB.

How would I fix this?

Comment: did you try this one: http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2013/01/05/unable-to-delete-rbs-blob-data-from-file-system-even-deleting-from-sharepoint-2010/